# Flair avatar not centered

Tags: bug, flair

My avatar isn't centered in specific site flair :

[image]

The screenshot is from meta, but the same problem is also on Stack Overflow. However the avatar on the combined flair is correctly centered :

[image]

How can I display my avatar on the flair to specific site as on the combined flair?

Comment: One problem is that [your avatar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP9s2.jpg) isn't a [1:1 aspect ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmbXB.png). Also this is a duplicate, in that respect. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329548/282094

Comment: @Rob - I agree, the picture needs retouching. But the avatar is correctly displayed on the profile picture . Also, the combined flair is correctly generated. It's weird that this only concerns specific site flair. Smell like a bug.

Comment: @Rob - I don't think this is a duplicate. The answer can be a solution, but the issue concerns only the specific site flair, the linked question concerns the profile picture. This hide the final issue that smell the bug.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the fact that the text is left-aligned on the combined flair and right-aligned on the per-site flair. Haven't really paid attention to it before and I'm not sure if that's intentional?

Comment: This has been known about for [several years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212287/282094), you'll need to have [10K reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213720/282094) to see the deleted answer by the OP; it's DIY, and you've made no change. See: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4485506.png  https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/282094.png - I don't have the problem, since my avatar is correctly sized.